# How to write a simplistic functional test plan?

Tags: design, testing, qa, engineering

I was given an assignment and it is fairly simple, just a special type of search for a special type of objects.

However, I was told to implement a set of functional tests and also provide a 1 page test plan. However, I am not sure what this plan has to include.

I have searched for samples on-line but they are too large for the scope of this assignment since it is supposed to be 1 page only.

I implemented 16 tests using JUnit, they test the expected results that a search produces.

Comment: Is there a Requirements Specification?  Write a test plan to implement tests that prove that each requirement has been fulfilled.

Comment: Not quite, the only requirements in my opinion would be the types of results that a search should produce... I got a list of them and the description of when that result has to be returned. They don't really detail much... I haven't really created a test plan before, I just discovered the concept yesterday ... Could you tell me what sections should the plan include so that it is simplistic but yet summarizes what is important in one-page? I am in Computer Science and this seems more on the side of Quality assurance which is why I don't have a lot of background on it.

Comment: In one page I think all you can do is write a short description of each of your existing tests.

Comment: A test plan can specify explicit test data and scenarios. But scenarios for a single search algorithm? Well maybe if the requirement is broad or various user interaction has significantly different effect on the input or output.  It should not be "a narrative flowchart" of the test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the following in form of a table: 
Item number - this is pretty much of 1,2,3,4.... (Just Basic numbering). Or if your program consists of a menu with numbers, you can use that as your numbers.

Item tested - these is about what item you are testing. E.g. You have a menu in a program, so these are the menu options like if you are adding a member for a certain organisation, the item tested will be for "Add Member"

Test Method - What are the methods you used while testing the program... E.g. Enter the menu number and click 'OK'

Expected Result - What do you expect to happen when you run the program.. like in these case, you want to add a member so the expected result for this would be 'Program add Member or Member added successfully'

Actual result - You can use ticks and crossed for these.

Hope these helps.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer but the first paragraph is very confusing.